# How to access data in an Excel shared file stored in SharePoint site?

Tags: excel, sharepoint

For a small part of a project, I need to read data from an Excel file stored in my client’s Sharepoint site.

My client gave me a link to access this file. In fact I can access it manually but I can’t access it programmatically. I’ve never worked with Sharepoint before.

I tried it using the Excel Interop like in [this](https://medium.com/@guiltabasa/how-to-read-excel-file-from-sharepoint-document-library-net-c-889374826d99) post.

The `excel.Worbooks.Open` line needed Microsoft to identify me so I typed my email address and password but I got this message (translated) :

> « Access denied. Contact your administrator. »

I tried with the manual URL and several others. A part of them used OData but it’s all the same (like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/requesting-excel-workbook-data-from-sharepoint-server-using-odata)).

Thanks to [this](https://blog.atwork.at/post/2017/12/29/Access-files-in-OneDrive-or-SharePoint-with-Microsoft-Graph-and-the-Excel-API) article, I also tried using Graph API but I received a 404 response.

I think the problem comes from the file rights.

---

So, if I'm true, my question is : what should my client do to allow me this programmatic access ? He is not an IT Pro.

If I'm wrong, where does this issue come from ? What can I do ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could access SHarePoint online file by [CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM).

Then read data in excel by [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/).

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                string password = "password";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", sec_pass);

                File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/lee/MyDoc3/Book.xlsx");
                ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> data=file.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
                {
                    //using (var stream = File.OpenRead(""))
                    //{
                    //    pck.Load(stream);
                    //}
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
                            pck.Load(mStream);
                            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                            bool hasHeader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)
                            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                            {
                                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                            }
                            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                            {
                                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                                {
                                    if (null != cell.Hyperlink)
                                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Hyperlink;
                                    else
                                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                                }
                                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine('1');

                        }
                    }



                }

                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
```